# Upload file to mediafire without api python script

Tags: python, upload, mediafire

I want to upload file to mediafire without API Delevoper(because when users use their accounts)

But I see mediafire api used Developer so i don't want to use it
I want to somethings like it:

```
import mediafire_uploader as mdf
mdf.create_login("USER_NAME","PASSWORD")
mdf.upload("file.txt")
```

And how can I do it?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload file to MediaFire without api,but i think it is source you want

```
from mediafire import MediaFireApi
from mediafire import MediaFireUploader
api = MediaFireApi()
uploader = MediaFireUploader(api)
session = api.user_get_session_token(
    email='YOUR_EMAIL',
    password='YOUR_PASSWORD',
    app_id='42511')

api.session = session
response = api.user_get_info()
fd = open('PATH_FILE', 'rb')
result = uploader.upload(fd, 'OUTPUT_FILENAME',
                         folder_key='FOLDER KEY')
```

Default app_id is 42511, i think you don't know it